# Can't add "python.analysis.extraPaths" in nvim for using jedi-ls

Tags: neovim, jedi-vim

I have a python repository, I'm using nvim as my ide and jedi-language-server for writing python files. I want to add a path like I can in my .vscode/settings.json -

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./<path>"
    ]
}⏎
```

This allows the editor to access my dependencies, how do i set the same in nvim

I used `:set path`, but I still get where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using `g:jedi#added_sys_path = [...]`, which is documented [here](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/master/doc/jedi-vim.txt#L548).

However I would also point out that in general with a good setup you should probably look into setting up your Python environments properly. In those cases, jedi-vim should always work properly. For your own libraries, `pip install -e .` might be interesting (to add them to the system path). For other software make sure you activate the correct virtualenv, which jedi-vim can then pick up.

Comment: i installed jedi-ls using mason.
```
.
./init.lua
./plugin
./plugin/packer_compiled.lua
./lua
./lua/ethsign
./lua/ethsign/init.lua
./lua/ethsign/packer.lua
./lua/ethsign/set.lua
./lua/ethsign/remap.lua
./after
./after/plugin
./after/plugin/colors.lua
./after/plugin/telescope.lua
./after/plugin/lsp.lua
./after/plugin/fugitive.lua
./after/plugin/treesitter.lua
./after/plugin/harpoon.lua
./after/plugin/undotree.lua
```
this is my nvim folder
Also, I'm using poetry to set environments, how do i set up the path for this env for jedi?